# Issue when creating cross-domain SignalR connection

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr.client

I have sites on 2 domains:

- a.com
- b.com

b.com hosts the SignalR Hub, and a.com tries to create a connection to b.com.

client JS:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://b.com/');
var notificationHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('notificationHub');
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
notificationHubProxy.client.resultReceived = function (result) {
    console.log(result);object.
}
```

server eventHub:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }

    public string Echo()
    {
        return "Notification hub is running normally";
    }

}
```

But I always get the following error on the client page:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'resultReceived' of undefined or
>   null reference.

As I checked, the 'notificationHubProxy.**client**' is undefined.

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a cross-domain issue. You are mixing the *dynamic proxy* and *proxyless* approaches. `$.hubConnection` and `createHubProxy` are from the proxyless API, but `.client` is available only with dynamic proxies. Check [the documentation about both](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection) and you will be able to fix it (I don't go further with code because I do not know which approach you really want to use).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the root cause.